# Symbol rate offset estimation

Tags: signal-analysis

I am confused between symbol rate offset, symbol timing offset and sampling clock offset. Can anyone tell be the difference between these terms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there are clear definitions for each term but here are my suggestions:

Symbol rate offset is the difference between the symbol rate entering a receiver and the symbol rate used by the demodulator. It could be measured in Hertz or parts per million (ppm).

Symbol timing offset is the difference between the time that a symbol should have been sampled and when it was sampled. It could be measured in seconds or fractions of the nominal baud duration.

Sampling clock offset is symbol rate offset multiplied by samples per symbol.

John

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Please read our [FAQ](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help) on more information about how to ask good questions and give good answer. StackExchange generally discourages signing your name in the answers, and instead picking a username filling out your profile information.

Comment: How to estimate symbol rate offset. For example transmitter is sending at a symbol rate of 100k. If the symbol rate is changes to 100K +/- delta. How to estimate delta?